# Table row hover, background change and click but have some child cells in the row have different properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-table

```
<table> 
<tr> 
<th>#</th> 
<th>Name</th> 
<th>Surname</th>
</tr> 

<tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" 
onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" 
onclick="DoNav('go.html');"> 

<td>1</td>
<td>John/td>
<td>Dump</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
 function ChangeColor(tableRow, highLight)
        {if (highLight)
        {tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '#F5FFDB';}
        else
        {tableRow.style.backgroundColor = '';}}
 function DoNav(theUrl)
        {document.location.href = theUrl;}
```

I use the following structure to draw the table. When I hover on a row it changes the background and anywhere I click on the row it will jump to the url. What I'm trying to do is have some id identifier (that maybe goes into `<td>`) which basically tells certain columns in a row to behave differently. Namely this is what I'm looking for:

```
<table> 
<tr> 
<th>#</th> 
<th>Name</th> 
<th>Surname</th>
</tr>   
<tr> 
<td id="hover_go_style_1">1</td>
<td id="hover_go_style_1">John</td>
<td id="hover_go_style_2">Dump</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention... the id="hover_go_style_1" would take me to one url and id="hover_go_style_2" would take me to another url. That's the "difference". As it is now with onClick the whole row takes me to one url, but in essence im trying to isolate cells. Not sure how to explain this better.

Comment: `What i'm trying to do is have some id identifier (that maybe goes into <td>) which basically tells certain columns in a row to behave differently` with what event `click`,`hover`,`keyup`.. not clear at all

Comment: How 'differently' do you want them to behave? Also, given you're using jQuery (or you've tagged the question with jQuery, perhaps erroneously), why are you using inline event-handling with the `onclick` attribute? In fact, even *without* jQuery, why are you using inline event-handling?

Comment: In addition to Davids questions: Why are you using JavaScript for hover effects? Use `tr:hover td { background: #F5FFDB; }` instead.

Comment: I forgot to mention... the `id="hover_go_style_1"` would take me to one url and `id="hover_go_style_2"` would take me to another url. That's the "difference". As it is now with `onClick` the whole row takes me to one url, but in essence im trying to isolate cells. Not sure how to explain this better.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using CSS for your hover color, it's much simpler there. Your click event can be much nicer hooked up and handled completely in your JavaScript also. I've added a `data-url` (HTML5-compatible) attribute to your row to define the URL.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/pQwd6/2/)

**HTML**

```
<table> 
<tr> 
<th>#</th> 
<th>Name</th> 
<th>Surname</th>
</tr>   
<tr data-url="go.html"> 
<td>1</td>
<td>John</td>
<td>Dump</td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$('tr[data-url]').click(function () {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('data-url');
});
```

**CSS**

```
tr:hover td {
    background-color:#F5FFDB;
}

/* Style the third column differently */
tr:hover td:nth-child(3) {
    background-color:#F00;
}
```